# AlertDialog is wider than it should expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

Today problem is that on Android 2.3.5 showing custom dialog is wrong. Dialog width is wider than it should be.

[image]

I tried using `20dp` instead of `wrap_content` in `TextView` as in `LinearLayout` with no success. I would like get rectangle shape with `wrap_content` as it is in `Android 4`.

Here is xml code for this custom dialog's view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Please wait" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a a custom dialog's code, anything else is not important.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        AlertDialog dialog;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_progressdialog,
                                       null);

        builder.setView(layout);

        //initializing textview

        dialog = builder.create();

        //do other stuff
```

On android 4.0.3 I get rectangle, so it looks ok - it is as I wanted. What might be the problem, does anyone find this kind of problem? Sorry, I don't have sample for `Android 4` - no phone today to make sample.

---

If I put inside also `progressbar` I am able to create square in android 4, but it is impossible to do it in Android 2.3.

Android 2.3.5

[image]

Android 4.0.4

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know whats wrong with your code. I want to have the ProgressDialog at the center of the screen. I have implemented it in to the Android 2.2.* and it works perfect in all devices even in android 4.*

I addition i have use style to the custom progressDialog. Please see below my code and you will come to know about it.

Java code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SplashActivity.this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
        dialog.getWindow();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.internet_dialog);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        Button retryBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.retryBtn);
        Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

        retryBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                                    // Some task
            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                                    // Some task
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
```

**CustomDialogTheme**

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>

    <!-- <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item> -->

</style>
```

And XMl file of my layout is: **internet_dialog.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/popup_shape"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/net_popup_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/internet_popup_heading"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/net_msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/internet_popup_msg"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/retryBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/internet_popup_retry" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/internet_popup_exit" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here, i havent give ant fix height/width but it seems perfect in all the layout of the any device.

try to adding style to your dialog and see result.
Hope it will help you.

Feel free for comments.   Enjoy Coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to ensure that your code behaves same on all the platforms, you can add layout params to your dialog view like this:

`layout.setLayoutparams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

`dialog.setView(layout);`

Ok its a work around, but if you are out of ideas , as I am for this issue, you can try:

calulate length of the text View by using `Paint.measureText();` and set it to dialog view param.
`layout.setLayoutparams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LENGTH_CALCULATED, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
builder.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //Controlling width and height.
```

Also try this

```
alertDialog.show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = 150;
lp.height = 500;
lp.x=-170;
lp.y=100;
alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: what u want? try other one solution

Comment: yes, but if I put two textview elements in vertical orientation - the second one is cutted. Dialog dimension doesn't show this element. Dialog height is very small, textview is not gravity centered - like it was ignoring other params

Comment: use relative layout instead of the linear layout. and set the textView to layout_leftOf or layout_rightOf in XML file according to your need. Also set the  android:layout_width="fill Parent"
    android:layout_height="fill-parent"

Comment: also you can set the margins-top/bottom of the textView in XML file which in result will increase the size of your dialog

Comment: yes but changing margin and setting width to fill or wrap doesn't work, it still ignores params. Thanks for a help. Please check it on android 2.3.5